# I want to add value to existing Json without double quotes

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Initially I have Json like this

```
{
  "softwareName": "MYSOFT",
  "softwareVersion": "0.4.5.9",
  "TimeZone": "2017-03-01T11:30:18.764103"
}
```

I want to add "status": {success: true} before “softwareName” for which I have done this

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
rss.Property("softwareName").AddBeforeSelf(new JProperty("status", "{success: true}"));
```

which give me results like this

```
{
  "status": "{success: true}",
  "softwareName": "MYSOFT",
  "softwareVersion": "0.4.5.9",
  "TimeZone": "2017-03-01T11:30:18.764103"
}
```

But, I want to get result like this;

```
{
  "status": {success: true},
  "softwareName": "MYSOFT",
  "softwareVersion": "0.4.5.9",
  "TimeZone": "2017-03-01T11:30:18.764103"
}
```

i.e **status** value without double quotes. How can I achieve this desired result? Because after that i'll have this view as show below

[image]

but currently I have it like this

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't "success" also be a JProperty, with true as its value, with that property being the value for the "status" property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do:

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
rss.Property("softwareName").AddBeforeSelf(new JProperty("status", JObject.Parse("{success: true}")));
```

Basically, you need to parse the string as a JSON object before adding it as property.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
obj  = {
  "softwareName": "MYSOFT",
  "softwareVersion": "0.4.5.9",
  "TimeZone": "2017-03-01T11:30:18.764103"
}

var newKey = "status"
var newVal = {success : true}

obj[newKey] = newVal
```

it gives

```
obj  = {
  "softwareName": "MYSOFT",
  "softwareVersion": "0.4.5.9",
  "TimeZone": "2017-03-01T11:30:18.764103"
  "status": {success : true}
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but you should show how you're creating your `obj` object.

Comment: didn't try your code. But, it seems that it'll work @krillgar